# How to find the schema of values in DStream at runtime?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-1.6

I use Spark 1.6 and Kafka 0.8.2.1.

I am trying to fetch some data from Kafka using Spark Streaming and do some operations on that data.

For that I should know the schema of the fetched data, is there some way for this or can we get values from stream by using field names?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It's **not** possible directly (esp. with the old Spark 1.6), but not impossible either.

Kafka sees bytes and that's what Spark Streaming expects. You'd have to *somehow* pass some extra information on fixed fields to get the schema (possibly as a JSON-encoded string) and decode the other field. It is not available out of the box, but is certainly doable.

---

As a suggestion, I'd send a message where `value` field would always be two-field data structure with the schema (of a value field) and the value itself (in JSON format).

You could then use one of [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) functions:

> **from_json(e: Column, schema: StructType): Column** Parses a column containing a JSON string into a StructType with the specified schema.

Given `from_json` was added in Spark 2.1.0, you'd have to register your own custom user-defined function (UDF) that'd deserialize the string value into a corresponding structure (just see how `from_json` [does it](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3040-L3041) and copy it).

Note that `DataType` object comes with [fromJson](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType$@fromJson(json:String):org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType) method that can "map" a JSON-encoded string into a `DataType` that would describe your schema.

> **fromJson(json: String): DataType**

Comment: Any suggestions for how to get it done in Spark-Streaming, or any other alternatives.

Comment: Here it comes...let me know how it sounds and...accept away!